# Can my pc with ip 192.168.0.102 reach gateway 192.168.1.1?

Tags: networking, router, ip, gateway

I'm a fool and I messed up, and now my router is configured to only accept requests to administration(settings) page from ip 192.168.0.102(I wanted to make it 192.168.1.102). The gateway is located at 192.168.1.1 Can I somehow connect to the gateway somehow? So that I could revert that setting... I tried changing my ip to 192.168.0.102 but I can't seem to reach the gateway...So what should I do to fix this issue? I don't really feel like resetting the router to factory defaults.
The router is TP-LINK btw.

Comment: Performing a reset is the simplest solution to this problem

Comment: well yeah,but before resetting I thought that perhaps there may be some other solutions I should try?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do it. If the router is 192.168.1.1/24, then 192.168.0.102 is on the WAN side, not the LAN side. You have several challenges:

1. The router might only let you administer it from the LAN side. This is pretty common in SoHo routers. There is no way to get 192.168.0.102 on the LAN side.
2. The router might block RFC1918 addresses like 192.168.0.102 from the WAN side. Because the LAN is 192.168.1.1/24, 192.168.0.102 must come from the WAN side. So if the router blocks private addresses from the WAN, you're out of luck.
3. You need to connect to the router's WAN side. If it's not an Ethernet port (if it's a cable or DSL port), you're probably out of luck.

But if those issues don't affect you, it could work. Configure a PC to 192.168.0.102/24 and setup a DHCP server to serve an IP address like 192.168.0.1 to the router's WAN port. Connect the router's WAN port to the PC's Ethernet port and try to reach the IP address your PC serves to the router's WAN side.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it when I have the opportunity.

Comment: No, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Set your computer to the IP address 192.168.0.102 and its subnet mask to 255.255.0.0. That will put the IP address 192.168.1.1 in the same subnetwork as your PC.

If this doesn't work, then resetting your router is indeed the only remaining way to recover from this scenario.

Comment: I see. Then I will just have to reset... Thanks!